# Drop the noun in a clause

Tags: grammar

Can I drop the noun ("text) in the following clause:

1) ..., regardless of whether a literary work is a pre-war text or a post-war text, ...

2) ..., regardless of whether a literary work is a pre-war or a post-war text, ...

Comment: Since a literary work is always a text, you don't need that word anywhere. _pre- or postwar_ works as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, I think

## 2) "..., regardless of whether a literary work is a pre-war or a post-war text, ..."

is fine. I think you can also, as KarlG commented, use "war" only once, as in:

"..., regardless of whether a literary work is a pre- or post-war text, ..."

Moreover, although your question is not about the [definition of literature](https://www.britannica.com/art/literature)*, I disagree with the comment "Since a literary work is always a text, you don't need that word anywhere" and think that using the word "text" removes any ambiguity about the "literature" being discussed. Writing, after all, is about clear communication.

*"To use the word writing when describing literature is itself misleading, for one may speak of 'oral literature' or 'the literature of preliterate peoples.'"